# Can I test telnet connectivity FROM multiple machines TO multiple machines, via a script?

Tags: shell-script, networking, telnet

I have 10 source machines and 10 destination machines. Each of those source machines need to connect to each of those destination machines.

I wrote a shell script which tests the telnet connectivity from one source machine to ten destination machines and this script is working. But I still have to first open the ten source machines in ten putty windows and run that script in each of them.

Any ideas on how can I run a single script from a single machine that will test the connections between all 100 source-destination combos?

Comment: Do you have a configuration management system that can easily be configured to run scripts on each of the source machines?

Comment: There's also [PuTTY scripting to log onto host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269885/putty-scripting-to-log-onto-host)

Comment: This is a Unix/Linux stackexchange, so not sure why you are talking about putty windows. You can use e.g. `ssh` to log into each of the 10 source machines, and then execute a script there to `telnet` into each of the destination machines. That requires `ssh` setup on the 10 source machines (after all, you can use putty...). If you don't have that, you need *something* else to automate. If you only have `telnet`, you can combine it with `expect`, but I really recommend using `ssh` instead.

Comment: Note: telnet is insecure, use ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Putty can do it (putty is poor mans ssh). However you can use putty to connect to one of the Unix machines, then use real ssh from there to orchestrate what you wont, so long as you can ssh from one of the machines to all of the other 9 (and it wont affect the results of your test).